# How to bind address in socket programming in c/c++?

Tags: c, sockets

I want to bind address "95.96.10.1"  with port number 8080. But when i tried below code it gave me error "address already in use".

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 8080 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
struct sockaddr_in address; 
int opt = 1; 
int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
char *hello = "Hello from server"; 

// Creating socket file descriptor 
if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
{ 
    perror("socket failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 


if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                              &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
                             sizeof(address))<0) 
{ 
    perror("bind failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

Please let me know how to bind address with port?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're binding to `INADDR_ANY` which means to bind to all interfaces:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

If you want to bind to a specific address, you need to set it.  You can use the `inet_addr` function to convert an IPv4 string to an address value:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("95.96.10.1");
```

Also, socket options can't be OR'ed together.  You can only operate on one at a time.

```
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

Comment: Check the address first.I want to bind with 95.96.10.1 this address but in my code i'm using default address from AF_INET family.
How to bind with this address 95.96.10.1

Comment: @Bond You should read a good reference for sockets like the book Unix Network Programming or Beej's Guide.

Comment: Is it possible to make port busy Which unix command or program can be used?I want to make port 8080 as busy

Comment: @Bond A port becomes busy when a socket it bound to it without using `SO_REUSEADDR` or `SO_REUSEPORT`.